# Save a data frame to S3 in feather format

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, feather

I have a data frame, let's say:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 4], 'b': [1, 3]})
```

I want to save it as a feather file to s3 but I can't find a working way to do it.

I tried to use [s3bp](https://github.com/shaypal5/s3bp) and [s3fs](http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but they don't do the trick.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

from io import BytesIO
from pyarrow.feather import write_feather

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 4], 'b': [1, 3]})

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
with BytesIO() as f:
    write_feather(df, f)
    s3_resource.Object('bucket-name', 'file_name').put(Body=f.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [storefact](https://github.com/blue-yonder/storefact) / [simplekv](https://github.com/mbr/simplekv) for this without writing to disk.

```
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow.feather import write_feather
import storefact

df = …
store = storefact.get_store('hs3', host="…", bucket="…", access_key="…", secret_key="…")
buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
write_feather(df, buf)
storage.put('filename.feather', buf.get_result().to_pybytes())
```

Comment: Does it works also for Python 3? I am not able to use `get_store` or `get_store_from_url`.

Comment: What do you mean for host here?

Comment: It also works for Python 3, I'm using it happily with it. Please post your error if you get one.

Comment: You can probably skip the host here. This is only there if you don't connect to Amazon S3 but another S3-compatible service.

Comment: The host argument is required. If I try with `host=''` I get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`. But I know that the acces_key and the secret are correct since I am using them in other contexts.

Comment: You should be able to connect to AWS using `s3.amazonaws.com` as the host.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple solution with just Pyarrow and Pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

s3 = pa.fs.S3FileSystem(region='us-east-1')

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

with s3.open_output_stream('my-bucket/path/to.feather') as f:
   pa.feather.write_feather(df, f)
```